# Django Tastypie: "error_message": "'bool' object has no attribute 'read'"

Tags: django, rest, backbone.js, tastypie

I am using **Backbone.js + Tastypie + Django** and am trying to save a model using patch = true to update the points on a model, like

```
this.save({
  points: newPoints
}, {
  patch: true
});
```

This issues a PUT request as it should with the request payload

```
points: 105
```

However, I get a 500 error message

```
{"error_message": "'bool' object has no attribute 'read'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 217, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 468, in dispatch_detail
    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 491, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1656, in patch_detail
    self.update_in_place(request, bundle, deserialized)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1679, in update_in_place
    return self.obj_update(bundle=original_bundle, **kwargs)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2209, in obj_update
    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 909, in full_hydrate
    value = field_object.hydrate(bundle)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 382, in hydrate
    value = make_aware(parse(value))

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 720, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 308, in parse
    res = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 356, in _parse
    l = _timelex.split(timestr)

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 150, in split
    return list(cls(s))

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 147, in next
    return self.__next__()  # Python 2.x support

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 141, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()

  File \"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py\", line 72, in get_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'read'
"}
```

Here is my model resource for UserProfile

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):

    """A resource for the UserProfile model."""

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'userprofile'
        authorization = Authorization()
        excludes = ['field_to_exclude']
        always_return_data = True
```

Does anyone have tips on how to debug this error?

Comment: This is a server side fault. Could you show some code on the server that handles the request?

Comment: I've added my server code--I'm using tastypie so my only customization is defining the resource. Since it is using the library and not my code, I'm not quite sure how to trace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a field which was a datetimefield which was null, and instead of showing up as a a datetime in the api call, is showed up as a boolean. I'm not sure why this happened, but I think this is a bug in tastypie, or I misunderstood something about the configuration, or both.

I excluded this field from the tastypie resource and I was able to PUT and PATCH successfully to the model.